# cannot set property '0' of undefined in angular 4

Tags: angular

I am facing the error when adding the data to dataTuple i=1 and j=0
(but i=0 and j=n it adding properly)

```
 for(let i=0; i<this._devices.length; i++ ) {
    for(let j=0;j<this._devices[i].devstatus.length;j++) {
       this.dataTuple[i][j] = [new 
       Date(this._devices[i].devtime[j]).getTime()+ 
       this.indiaUTC ,this._devices[i].devstatus[j]];
    }
 }
```

[error screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/swF1A.png)

In the above img datatuple[0][n] is working but datatuple[n][0]  not assigning

Comment: what is _`devices` can you post the structure?

Comment: possibly there are no data for i=1 in _devices.

Comment: from server am getting devices list along with device data

Comment: You have to make sure that you have `devtime` and `devStatus` in `_devices`. Maybe you only have data in `devtime[0]`, not in `devtime[n]`, or maybe you don't have `devtime` at all? Do a `console.log(devtime[i])`, to see the data you have

Comment: i have both devtime[n] and devstatsu[n] data.       I attached screenshot check it

Comment: what is written on line 51 in `data.component.ts`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 for(let i=0; i<this._devices.length; i++ ) {
    for(let j=0;j<this._devices[i].devstatus.length;j++) {
       this.dataTuple[i]= this.dataTuple[i] || []
       this.dataTuple[i][j] = [new 
       Date(this._devices[i].devtime[j]).getTime()+ 
       this.indiaUTC ,this._devices[i].devstatus[j]];
    }
 }
```

I support that this.dataTuple[0] was create somewhere in code previously, thats why first row is filled ok.

Comment: Thanks for your help its working fine can u explain please

Comment: this.dataTuple[1][1] means add element to this.dataTuple[i] array. But we should create this array first

Comment: this.dataTuple[i]= this.dataTuple[i] || [] means - if array exists - then assign it to itself (so same array will stay). If it doesnt exist - then assign with empty array []